# What species is Abraham the Mage?

Tags: secrets-of-immortal-nicholas-flamel

During the course of the *The Secrets of the Immortal Nicholas Flamel* series, Abraham the Mage is kind of a mysterious figure. He's been around for a very long time already at the time of Danu Talis, and nobody is sure what *species* he is.

Characters over the course of the series wonder who this guy is, and speculate several times as to what species he may be.

Do we ever get to know what species he is? Do we have enough clues to figure it out?

Comment: I'd have to go back and check, but I'd say Elder. Wasn't he turning to gold?

Comment: @Adamant - yes, his Change was a hint toward Elder, but given that nobody in-universe seems to be entirely sure...